# GIMP how to automate gaussian blur then mode divide on several pages

Tags: gimp, image-editing

I have a multi-page PDF loaded as layers in GIMP. I want to automate the following actions in sequence:

1. Select and make first layer visible, others non-visible
2. Duplicate layer
3. Apply Gaussian Blur
4. Change mode to Divide
5. Merge visible layers
6. Move to next layer, repeat 1 to 4

Actually, automating steps 2 to 4 is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing any code, if you have not got too many layers (or have enough RAM):

1. Create a single layer holding all your pages.
2. Apply your operations.
3. Split the resulting big layer into pages again.

Operations 1 and 3 can be done using the [`ofn-layer-tiles` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).

Otherwise you would need a custom script. Not that hard if you have some programmming experience (plenty of examples in the page linked).

Comment: I have some programming experience, Python actually. So I might have a chance if someone guides me with custom script.

Comment: I downloaded `ofn-layer-tiles` script, installed. I don't know how to use it. Obviously I have to join layers first, as all pages are imported in separate layers.

Comment: The ZIP contains a HTML doc. Read it. The script takes all your layers (as a stack) and spreads them side by side as a big image (and vice-versa).

Comment: Otherwise a simple example not so far from what you want to do is in `ofn-difference-layer` (freshly uploaded). Further discussion best done [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Forum-Scripting-questions) or at least on SO, because this is beyond the realm of GDSE.

Comment: Oh, I got it all finally. Thank you so much. And it's amazing what 8gig RAM can do :)